# Instantiate a view controller from UIStoryBoard after using TyphoonAssemblyActivator

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

After using the new API with the `TyphoonAssemblyActivator` interface, I would like to instantiate a `UIViewController` located within a `UIStoryBoard`, but it misses the `factory` instance.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TyphoonAssemblyActivator` is useful for bootstrapping Typhoon in a library or somewhere within a legacy application. For a fully-Typhoon powered application its better to use [plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration).

Just add the name of your `TyphoonAssembly` classes in your app's plist file, and optionally inject your AppDelegate class. Having done this:

- Instances of Storyboard will be TyphoonStoryboard, behave just like regular storyboards with the added benefit that dependencies are injected. You can define a definition for injections in an assembly or use the [auto-injection](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Auto-injection-%28Objective-C%29) macros.
- Bootstrapping Typhoon this way also means that UIStateRestoration in Storyboards works as expected.

If for some reason you did want to create a TyphoonStoryboard manually you could create a definition for one in the assembly as:

```
- (UIStoryboard*)storyboard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] 
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) 
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

            [initializer injectParameterWith:@"StoryboardName"];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];
    }];
}
```